# Continue matching after one case in matched

Tags: python, pattern-matching

Is there any way to continue matching even after one case is matched, for example,

```
dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
match dct:
  case {}: print('using {}', dct)
  case {'a': 1}: print("using {'a': 1}", dct)
  case {'a': 1, 'b': 2}: print("using {'a': 1, 'b': 2}", dct)
```

outputs,

```
using {} {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

but I want the pattern matching to continue after matching with one pattern, to get the output,

```
using {} {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
using {'a': 1} {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
using {'a': 1, 'b': 2} {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Please explain more about your question.

Comment: Despite the similarity, a `match` statement is not meant to be used like a switch statement in languages like C or Java. For the behavior you want, continue to use individual `if` or `match` statements.

Answer (score 1):

match/case Structural Pattern Matching doesn't support continuing after a match is found, it will stop at the first successful match or reach the wildcard case.
https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#use-continue-and-break-in-case-clauses

In your example all the cases match to `dct`.

You could use multiple match/case statements, but this almost defeats the purpose?

```py
dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
match dct:
    case {}: print('using {}', dct)
match dct:
    case {'a': 1, }: print("using {'a': 1}", dct)
match dct:
    case {'a': 1, 'b': 2}: print("using {'a': 1, 'b': 2}", dct)
```

Output:

```
using {} {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
using {'a': 1} {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
using {'a': 1, 'b': 2} {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

It does become somewhat useful if `dct` changes though:

```py
dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 42}
match dct:
    case {}: print('using {}', dct)
match dct:
    case {'a': 1, }: print("using {'a': 1}", dct)
match dct:
    case {'a': 1, 'b': 2}: print("using {'a': 1, 'b': 2}", dct)
```

Output:

```
using {} {'a': 1, 'b': 42}
using {'a': 1} {'a': 1, 'b': 42}
```